# Sorting alphanumeric and numeric column of tab delimited text file in natural way

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, unix, command-line

I am trying to sort a file based on all two columns

Eg:

> chr19      1070019 1070020
>   
> chr16   869712  869713
>   
> chr1    1378131 1378132
>   
> chr12   189386  189387
>   
> chr4    254941  254942
>   
> chr16   1476500 1476501
>   
> chr2    1476810 1476811
>   
> chr19   313283  313284
>   
> chr17   595817  595818
>   
> chr18   656897  656898
>   
> chr19   1061829 1061830

I Tried `sort -t $\t -k1,1 2,2 <filename>` but doesn't work.

I want the output to be sorted by first column and second column based on first column.
I want to do a natural sort. Not lexical sorting.

Eg:

> chr1   1378131 1378132
>   
> chr2    1476810 1476811
>   
> chr4    254941  254942
>   
> chr12   189386  189387
>   
> chr16   869712  869713
>   
> chr16   1476500 1476501
>   
> chr17   595817  595818
>   
> chr18   656897  656898
>   
> chr19   313283  313284
>   
> chr19   1061829 1061830
>   
> chr19   1070019 1070020

Anyone any idea?

Comment: I tried. I does not sort the second column and the first column is sorted lexically.

Comment: It's because you don't want to sort numerically as suggested.  You need natural sort, use `-V`.

Answer (score 2):

This should take care of it

```
sort -k1.4,1n -k2,2n file
```